# Two monitors: 21:9 and 16:9 laptop - scaling problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, 17.04

I just connect to a 15 'FullHD (my laptop) a new monitor 29` 21: 9 2048x1536 and I got some problems:

- When I click on the mouse, the cursor does not indicate where I click, and the place that is actually clicked is shifted to the left about 10cm.
- Windows are no longer scaling properly. Even when both screens have a well-set resolution in ARandr, the problem is not solved.

Any suggestions?

My graphics card and drivers:  NVIDIA Driver Version: 381.22 Quadro M2000M

Nvidia can't change setting of my laptop screen and it writes

> prime displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings

Here's an `xrandr` dump:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
        DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        DP-1 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 673mm x 284mm
           2560x1080     60.00*+
           1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
           1680x1050     59.95  
           1600x900      60.00  
           1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
           1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
           1152x864      75.00  
           1024x768      75.03    60.00  
           800x600       75.00    60.32  
           720x576       50.00  
           720x480       59.94  
           640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
        DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
        eDP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
           1920x1080     60.02 +  59.93  
           1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
           1600x1024     60.17  
           1400x1050     59.98  
           1280x1024     60.02  
           1440x900      59.89  
           1280x960      60.00  
           1360x768      59.80    59.96  
           1152x864      60.00  
           1024x768      60.04    60.00  
           960x720       60.00  
           928x696       60.05  
           896x672       60.01  
           960x600       60.00  
           960x540       59.99  
           800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
           840x525       60.01    59.88  
           800x512       60.17  
           700x525       59.98  
           640x512       60.02  
           720x450       59.89  
           640x480       60.00    59.94  
           680x384       59.80    59.96  
           576x432       60.06  
           512x384       60.00  
           400x300       60.32    56.34  
           320x240       60.05  
          1680x1050 (0x46) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
                h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
                v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
          1280x1024 (0x4a) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
                h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
                v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
          1024x768 (0x51) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
                h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
                v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
          800x600 (0x58) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
                h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
                v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
          640x480 (0x61) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
                h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
                v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```